# angular: Combining two arrays in angular template for display

Tags: angular

I have following display code inside a ng-repeat:

```
<span ng-switch-default>
       {{ a.x ? a.y : a.z }}
</span>
```

a.y, a.z are arrays, and this results in display of array members separated by ',', inside [], like:

```
["1", "2", "3"]
```

I have another field a.m, also an array, and for some cases I would like its values to be combined.
So if a.y is ["1", "2", "3"] , a.m is ["One", "Two", "Three"], I want display as:

```
["1: One:, "2:Two", "3:Three"]
```

What is idiomatic way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Array.map

```js
const array1 = ["1", "2", "3"]
const array2 = ["One", "Two", "Three"]

const combinedArray = array1.map((element, index) => element + ':' + array2[index]);
console.log(combinedArray);
// ["1:One","2:Two","3:Three"]
```